# Why is <form> a block element?

Tags: html, forms

The purpose of a `<form>` element, IMO, is semantic not presentational - the element is there to define an area with elements which can be sent to the server.

Why then, does the browser (and, I assume in the spec), specify display:block in the user agent stylesheet? Surely, if you want to have the form be a block, you can just wrap it in a div element?

Usually, I just put form { display: inline } into my css to override this. Still, I'm wondering if there was a good reason for making the `<form>` display as a block by default, or if it's just been kept that way for legacy reasons.

Comment: "if you want to have the form be a block, you can just wrap it in a div element?" Or even better than wrapping it you can use the [`display`  CSS property](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#display-prop).

Comment: Yeah. I guess my point is more that it should be the default for it to not affect your formatting, not the opposite.

Answer (score 18):

I assume this is because a `<form>` will very often contain other block level elements (div's for structure, or though I cringe at the thought, tables to help organize form fields, etc.).  And having an inline element that contains block elements, while entirely possible, is semantically questionable.

I completely agree with your point about `<form>` not being presentational, but at the same time it makes sense to me that it would be a block element, given how the tag is generally used.

Comment: Dammit, beat me by like 10 seconds :D Good answer.

Comment: Perhaps then, the real solution here is to add another mechanism for generating POST requests in browsers other than the `<form>` tag. It doesn't make sense to me that if I want to add a button which does a post, I need to introduce an element which will affect formatting unless I override it.

Comment: @Jords - You can do that already if you really want to.  For instance by using [jQuery.post()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/).  Of course you have to gather up all the parameters you want yourself, so it's less convenient than using a `<form>`, but the option does exist.

Comment: I meant to mention, I can/do do this using javascript sometimes, but it seems like it shouldn't really be a requirement to do this.

Answer (score 3):

[HTML 3.2](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html32#block) defines the `<FORM>` element as a block level element. The current behaviour of browsers regarding this element is certainly for backwards compatibility.

Comment: Does that mean newer specs have a differing opinion then?

Comment: No, not at all. I'm saying that the reason today's browsers treat `<FORM>` as a block level element, is because HTML 3.2 did so (before CSS gave authors the option to decide any other way).

Answer (score 1):

A `<form>` is meant to be semantic AND presentational. It is semantic by nature, but also forbidden to embed one form within another, implying that it is meant to be a definite container for all of its content (form controls, and other block/inline content). Additionally, inline nodes cannot contain block level nodes, at least not by spec, which would limit the `<form>` tag by default.